# How to remove the Beta tag for all users in Play Store after promoting build to production?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Our app was in Open Testing. We had about 6k users. Since then we moved to Production track this week. The prod aab version number is greater than the last uploaded open testing version number.

But all our old users are still seeing the Beta tag in the Play Store app title. They can only give private feedback, not ratings/reviews. Users who were not earlier in the testing track don't see the Beta tag.

One solution that works for each individual user is to go to the Play Store page and click on Leave Beta. This sends user to Prod track. But we can't go and ask every user to do this.

Will hitting Pause Track on Open Testing track remove the Beta tag and make all existing users as Prod users? Or is there any other way to move all users of the Beta track to the Prod track?

Thanks!